Why is element fidgeting on hover/active?
I have a navigation menu. When someone hovers over one of the options I want the dash next to the option to expand accordingly so that the selected menu option is indented (and a different color) compared to the rest.
I have it working pretty much how I want it except for on the transform of the dash it glitches down one pixel.


html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#application-layer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: blue;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#nav {
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 150px;
  width: 500px;
}

.navContainer a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 3px;
  font: bold 12px 'Navigation';
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #909eb2;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navLine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  font: 14px 'Title';
  color: #909eb2;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: default;
}

.navContainer:hover {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navContainer:hover .navLine {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: scale(2.25, 1);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer:hover a {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: translateX(38px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer.active a {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: translateX(38px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer.active .navLine {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: scale(2.25, 1);
  transition: 0.2s;
}
<div class="container">

  <div id="application-layer">
    <div class="menu">
      <aside class="navigator" id="nav">
        <nav>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>FIRST</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>SECOND</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>THIRD</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Am I dealing with the dash or the hover incorrectly? For the dash I created a separate element so I could stretch it separately from the text...

The problem is not evident on my Mac; either in Chrome or Safari. Everything expands smoothly horizontally, I can’t see any glitches.

I don't notice any glitches on Firefox (or Chrome) on Win11, either. The only thing that looks weird are the colors you've chosen; they're quite garish and make it hard to see what it is you want us to see.

I don't see it grows down by 1 px. However, if you are talking about the very slight subpixel change at the end after zooming in 500%, I'm guessing this has something to do with how Chrome handle subpixel rendering. This didn't happen in Firefox from what I see.

You can just use an empty div with 1 px border to do similar job without using scale. However, if using such a thin line is required, one thing you can do is add translate3d(0, 0, 0) perspective(1px) to make the flicker nearly invisible. For some reason any other method such as will-change I've tried to force GPU rendering doesn't work, neither does font-smooth does anything on it.


html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#application-layer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

rect:hover {
  fill: blue;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

#nav {
  /* position: absolute; */
  top: 150px;
  width: 500px;
}

.navContainer a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 3px;
  font: bold 12px 'Navigation';
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #909eb2;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: 0.2s;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navLine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  font: 14px 'Title';
  color: #909eb2;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: default;
}

.navContainer:hover {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.navContainer:hover a {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: translateX(38px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer.active a {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: translateX(38px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer:hover .navLine {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: scale(2.25, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navContainer.active .navLine {
  color: #E2E8F0;
  transform: scale(2.25, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}
<div class="container">
  <div id="application-layer">
    <div class="menu">
      <aside class="navigator" id="nav">
        <nav>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>FIRST</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>SECOND</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navContainer">
            <div class="navLine">——</div><a>THIRD</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Yeah chrome seems to do it differently... I tried adding translate3d(0, 0, 0) perspective(1px) b/c I thought that sounded smart and it worked except it created a little pimple in the middle of the lines. Weird, anyways, I gave the empty div a try (so simple, I should have thought of that) and it works like a charm. Thank you.

I can't see little pimples in the middle of the lines in my browser but glad that empty divs works for you!
